# How can I get values from form in controller in rails without using form_helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get values from form in controller in rails without using form_helper? By using simple html form, and simple input text-boxes, select-boxes, radio-boxes, etc?

Comment: Explain a little more ?

Comment: If i use form_for helper, and inside it i use text_fields, password_fields, etc i can get the values entered by user here in controller using params[]. I am asking that can i use simple html form and simple input boxes, radio boxes etc and get the values entered by user there in controller?

Comment: **form_for** is meant to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a form tag then:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Inside form_tag You can use other helpers like button_tag, field_tag etc, or You can simply write an html code.

The reason why You need to use form_tag or form_for is because of the CSFR security.
If You inspect a form generated by those helpers You will find a hidden field where Rails puts an authenticity token. When user submits a form Rails uses this tag to verify if the form submitted is coming from the current app and not some external call.